# Multicasting in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, multicast

I've got a lot of questions regarding [this e.g.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html&rct=j&q=server%20broadcast%20multiple%20clients%20ajva&ei=39KITse6AcvyrQfPhZiUAw&usg=AFQjCNGiESrMY8oElzpp6uVFdnOXbp7TQQ&cad=rja). Hence enumerating them:

1. Why do they use datagram sockets? Is there another alternative to them?
2. I'm trying to send objects over the datagram sockets in [this example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip40.html?page=2). It takes a *long* time for the server to receive the object from the client's side. Is there any alternative to that as well?

Note - I'm trying to integrate both programs to make a network discovery program wherein the client replies with it's details in the form of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, you need datagrams (UDP) because tcp is a connection oriented protocol. i.e., each connection is for communication between one server and one client. You can have multiple clients connected to a server, but they'd all be individual unicast communication.

Regarding your second question, I don't think a delay you observe is due to your code. Post more details about your topology, etc. to help solve that issue.